# Using Everything search with Emacs/Anything under Windows

Tags: windows, search, emacs

So I've started to use Anything with Emacs. You can use 'locate' with anything, but you can also use VoidTools' 'Everything' (which is actually the default for 'Windows-NT' systems.

It took a little bit of prodding, but I have command line Everything working on my system. I get results back from it while using anything-locate or anything-for-files.

Everything works fine except I get the dreaded ^M (control-M) at the end of the lines that es returns to me. That means when I use anything to open the file, it doesn't work.

Anyone have any help on how to fix values that es returns, or alternately, strip off the ^M before trying to open the file?

Answer (score 1):

Ah-ha, in the end, it was my fault.

Be careful when messing around with the process-coding-system-alist, and make sure that it's something that really needs to be done. I modified this in the past thus:

```
(setq process-coding-system-alist (cons '("bash" . (raw-text-unix . raw-text-dos)) 
                                 process-coding-system-alist))
```

And I don't need to do that anymore. It meant that the files being passed up from Everything were being interpreted Unix style, and the CR/^M were showing up. By commenting out this line, I solved my own problem.